# Download attached file

Tags: javascript, reactjs, download

Is there a way to download files attached using Paperclip without using libraries?

My goal is to allow the user to download the file as soon as the file is uploaded and before it is sent to the backend.

I found the way to make it working with [file-saver](https://www.npmjs.com/package/file-saver)

However, I was wondering if that can be done without the library?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the js-file-download package.
https://www.npmjs.com/package/js-file-download